# How to find tetrads corresponding to a given metric?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

In General Relativity, sometimes doing calculations with a set of orthonormal tetrads

$h^{a}_{\mu}$

where $h^{a}_{\mu}$$h^{b}_{\nu}$$\eta_{ab}=g_{\mu\nu}$ for some metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is easier than doing calculations with the metric itself.

However, in general, how can I find a tetrad corresponding to a given metric? That is, given $g_{\mu\nu}$, is there a general procedure used to find $h$ such that $h^{a}_{\mu}$$h^{b}_{\nu}$$\eta_{ab}=g_{\mu\nu}$ ?

More specifically, I'm trying to find tetrads corresponding to the following 5-dimensional black brane metric

$ds^{2}=-2u_{\mu}dx^{\mu}dr-r^{2}f(br)u_{\mu}u_{\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}+r^{2}P_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$

where $f,P,u$ are given.

Comment: Probably better methods but you can really just do it as a system of equations using the matrix product really.